# Maximum likelihood: Bernoulli

Tags: probability, self-study, maximum-likelihood, naive-bayes, bernoulli-distribution

I would really appreciate if anyone you can explain how it went from step 1 to the answer provided below. This is from the book Doing Data Science by Cathy O'Neil and Rachel Schutt pages 101 to 102.

I have provided my answers with the steps I took to get there.

$p(x|c) = \Pi_j\theta_{jc}^{x_j}(1-\theta_{jc})^{(1-x_j)}$

Take ln both sides:

$ln(p(x|c)) = ln(\Pi_j\theta_{jc}^{x_j}(1-\theta_{jc})^{(1-x_j)})$

Known:

$\Pi_j \theta_{jc}^{x_j} = \theta_{jc}^{(\sum_{j} x)}$

$\Pi_j(1-\theta_{jc})^{(1-x_j)}  = (1-\theta_{jc})^{n - \sum_j x}$

Substitute the known into the equations:

$ln(p(x|c)) = ln(\theta_{jc}^{(\sum_{j} x)} * (1-\theta_{jc})^{n - \sum_j x})$

Expand the muliplication:

$ ln(p(x|c)) = ln(\theta_{jc}^{(\sum_{j} x)}) + ln((1-\theta_{jc})^{n - \sum_j x})$

Simply:

$ln(p(x|c)) = (\sum_{j} x)ln(\theta_{jc}) + ({n - \sum_j x})ln(1-\theta_{jc})$

$ln(p(x|c)) = (\sum_{j} x)ln(\theta_{jc}) - (\sum_j x)ln(1-\theta_{jc}) + (n)ln(1-\theta_{jc})$

My answer:

$ln(p(x|c)) = (\sum_{j} x)ln(\frac{\theta_{jc}}{1-\theta_{jc}})   + (n)ln(1-\theta_{jc})$

Text book answer:

$ln(p(x|c)) = (\sum_j x_j) ln(\frac{\theta_j}{1-\theta_j}) + \sum_j log(1-\theta_j)$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated! To make your question more interesting to those who might answer it, you may find it helpful to provide some context to start. Something like a restatement of the actual problem/exercise might help, and (if possible) some note about why the quesion is interesting as more than an exercise in symbol manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to the book, but I think you've some typos in its answer. The parentheses should cover both $x_j$ and the $\ln$ term because outside we have no $j$ index. Also, we have $\theta_{jc}$, not $\theta_j$.

If we start from taking log of both sides,
$$\begin{align}p(x|c)&=\sum_{j}\ln(\theta_{jc}^{x_j}(1-\theta_{jc})^{1-x_j})\\&=\sum_jx_j(\ln\theta_{jc}+(1-x_j)\ln(1-\theta_{jc})) \\&=\sum_j x_j\ln \left(\frac{\theta_{jc}}{1-\theta_{jc}}\right)-\sum_j 
\ln(1-\theta_{jc}) \end{align}$$

Your mistakes start from the "Known" section, e.g.
$$\prod_j\theta_{jc}^{x_j}\neq\theta_{jc}^{\sum_j x_j}$$
because $\theta_{jc}$ is dependent on $j$.